# Run service every 30 minutes without using wakelocks

Tags: java, android, json

> **tl;dr:** my app doesn't update my `SharedPreferences` with the last value from the server because sometimes the phone is sleeping.

## Explanation:

I'm new in this android world, and I've been working on my first "real" application but I'm having a few issues right know...

### Here's how I need my application to work:

> - Check every 30 minutes for new data (data is pulled from a json file on my server)
> - If the data is different from the stored on the phone, then store the new data and send a notification to the user. (I'm using **`SharedPreferences`** for the "storage")

### Here's what I used to try to achieve that:

> - `MainActivity.java` / **Activity** (my main activity, duh')
> - `cargarJson.java` / **AsyncTask** (a class that pulls json data and returns a jsonobject). Cargar = Load (in spanish)
> - `DolarService.java` / **IntentService** (The service creates a loadJson object and execute it, then sends the notification).
> - `AlarmReceiver.java` / **BroadcastReceiver** (It's a receiver that has an `AlarmManager` that executes my ***`DolarService`*** every 30 minutes and runs everytime the phone boot up and when the user runs the app for the first time).

I kind of managed to do it, but the problem is that I don't want to use wakelocks because it drains the battery really fast.

My `AlarmManager` doesn't use wakelocks so when it sends the notification every 30 minutes it contains the last value stored in the SharedPreferences when the phone was "awake" and not the new data from the server.

**Here's my source:**
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d5cccf5ba331f041630e

**My question:** how do I keep my up-to-date data in my `SharedPreferences` (updating it every 30 minutes) without using wakelocks. Also, is something wrong with my approach to do this app ?

*Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor english, I tried my best to explain my situation!*

Comment: You might want to look at GCM as an alternative to waking up with an alarm to poll the server.

Comment: "I don't want to use wakelocks because it drains the battery really fast" -- not when you use them correctly. You only need an acquired `WakeLock` from the time your `BroadcastReceiver` gets control until the `IntentService` completes its work. This pattern is embodied in Google's `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, and separately in my `WakefulIntentService`. Neither should cause significant battery drain if you are only doing a little bit of work every 30 minutes. That being said, Mr. Stratton's GCM suggestion would be even better, if you have control over the server environment.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks!, I tried GCM first before coding what I have now but all the tutorials and guides I found were outdated and used the GCM.jar file that is now deprecated!

Comment: @CommonsWare I will look in to that, thank you! ps: If you can find a good example of the "new" GCM (without the GCM.jar file) please post it here!

Comment: Well, here's my sample of the new GCM API from my book: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient2 It includes conversions of some of the old GCM.jar code into equivalents for use with the new API.

Comment: @CommonsWare you should have posted comment#2 as an answer. There is an answer but nothing to accept.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're using wake locks.  You can make sure of this, however, by removing your  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` from your manifest, and then you'll know for certain that your application isn't acquiring a wakelock, because it doesn't have permission.

Edit:

You're using your `IntentService` incorrectly.  See the documentation on how to implement an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).  An `IntentService` already creates it's own worker thread, similar to an `AsyncTask`, so executing an `AsyncTask` within an intent service is unnecessary in your case.  Instead, you should pull out everything in your `AsyncTask` and implement it in your `IntentService`'s `onHandleIntent()`, rather than it's `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods.

The other option would be to use a normal `Service`, and stop it in your `AsyncTask's onPostExecute()` method.

Also, this is a little off topic, but when passing a context to another object, you should use a `WeakReference<T>`:

```
WeakReference<Context> context;

public cargarJson(String jsonUrl, Context context) {
this.jsonUrl = jsonUrl;
this.context = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
}
```

Comment: Oops, I just forgot to delete that line in the manifest, but it's not waking the device up because I haven't "used it" in the java code! edit: the thing is that I was wondering if I could achieve what I wanted without using wakelocks

Comment: If you're only updating every 30 minutes or so, and from the looks of it, it looks like its a pretty simple and quick task, it shouldn't have the much strain on battery life.  The other option is to just increase the check up interval to > 30 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, my service is still running when the phone is sleeping and is sending notifications every 30 minutes but with outdated information (and this is my main issue)!

Comment: Sorry about that, the title was a bit misleading.  I think I found your issue, though - see the edit.

Comment: Yeah, I realized the title was misleading as soon as I posted the question, sorry about that! Regarding the commit issue, you're right, I forgot to commit, but that is not the "important" data (the one that updates with the json information), that data is in the onPostExecute method of cargarJson.java. I added the commit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All things are fine. But its good if you use a backgorund service for your server operations and start this service through the AlarmManager followed by PendingIntent in every 30 minutes.